# Sending a query every time a user clicks a button

Tags: r, shiny

I am making an app where the user has a textInput field, writes some text and then clicks submit. Under the hood the app should convert this one vector into a n size vector where n is the number of words provided from the user. My algorithm should then apply these words into a query and then download data from a database.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("key", label = "Key words", value = "price"),
  actionButton("submit","Submit"),
  submitButton("Update", icon("refresh")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server<-function(input, output){
      keywords<-strsplit("key", " ")[[1]]
      query1<-"SELECT * FROM \"domain\" WHERE x < 5"
      query3<-query2(keywords)
      query<-paste(query1,query3)
      query_data <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
      output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
       query_data
  })
}
```

con is set correctly. If I run query_data with custom keywords its working so there is an issue with the names provided by the user. My_table should print the results from the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  query_data <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    keywords <- strsplit(input$key, " ")[[1]]
    query1 <- "SELECT * FROM \"domain\" WHERE x < 5"
    query3 <- query2(keywords)
    query <- paste(query1,query3)
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    query_data()
  })
}
```

Comment: Ok, its working. What should I do if I want to save just the third column from mytable as a new df?